# Better design for abstraction of Db with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

My application processes different kind of messages and stores them in a database. Right now I have used the following design:

Database class:

```
class DbObject
{
public:
    // read/write object members from/to DB 
    virtual void readFromDb() = 0;
    virtual void writeToDb() = 0;

    // Other stuff, db connection etc.
    void doDbStuff();
}
```

Base class for Messages:

```
class BaseMsg
{
public:
    // read/write object members from/to DB 
    virtual std::string toXml() = 0;
    virtual void fromXml(const & std::string s) = 0;
}
```

Message types A, B etc.

```
class MsgA : public BaseMsg, DbObject
{
public:
    std::string toXml();
    void fromXml(const & std::string s);

    void readFromDb();
    void writeToDb();
}
```

This design works well, each processed message gets it's own object, can be written to XML, read from XML, stored and read to/from the database with message specific stuff (implemented in MsgA).

However, at the moment we are considering porting the application to a new platform, where the current database is not available, so we would use an additional database type.

Normally I would have now have a base class for database access and child classes for each database type. But with the current design is not possible, because I don't want to have a MsgADatabase1 class and a MsgADatabase2 class, etc.

Is there any design  pattern, where I could keep my current design in principle, but hide the currently used database type behind some kind of abstraction layer?

Comment: All databases have INSERT, QUERY, DELETE and UPDATE functionality. Simply make an abstract base class that supports those four (and possible other) operations, and child classes that implements those operations with a specific database. Then use a pointer to the base class in your `DbObject` class, and use it to do your operations on the database.

Comment: To know what actual instance of the abstract database conection class you should use, have a factory function that takes the type of the database as argument, ad return a new instance of the correct object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. First thought would be see `DbOject` as an adapter.**

According to the Gang of Four, the **[adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)** shall offer a target interface for an adapted object (the concrete database object) either via multiple inheritance or composition.

In the context of your multiple inheritance, this design would impose that for every `DbObject` you inherit in the message, its constructor would create a one to one link with a DB specific oject.  But how can the constructor know wich concrete db class to create ?

**2. Next thought: combine this adapter with abstract factory**

THe most natural pattern for creating a concrete database dependent object that instantiate an abstract database independent obect would be to use a an **[abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)**.

Combined with the adapter, you'd have the following scenario:

- at startup, an virtual factory (class `Database`) object gets instantiated with the concrete database dependent factory (`class DatabaseBrandA : public Database`)
- the virtual factory provides a function to create `DbIndependentObject`. The concrete factory implements this function, providing its own concrete objects (of `class DbBrandAdependentObject : public DbIndependentObject`)
- Every time a message is created, the base `DbObject` adaptor request the virtual factory to instantiate a new object.  So it refers to a `DbIndependentObject` implemented by a `DbBrandAdependentObject`)

However, I don't know if the content of your `DbObject` is really so rich that it needs a one to one relation with a database specific object.  Is such a complex pattern not an overkill here ?

**3.Final conclusion: the adaptor combined with the proxy design pattern**

I suspect that your `DbObject` is only meant as a handy way to get virtual read and write functions implemented by the derived message object, that can be called whenever database interaction is needed.

If your current code is designed so that `DbOject` encapsulates everything which is related to the database, you simply need a **[proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)**  to this database.

This would work according to the following scenario:

- at startup, an abstract database (class `Database`) object gets instantiated with a concrete database (`class DatabaseBrandA : public Database`)
- Every time a message is created, the base `DbObject` acts as proxy referring to the  Database object.
- Everytime a database operation needs to be performed, the  `DbObject` acts as adaptor for the message by providing the needed read write functions.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I think option 2. seems to be a good solution, but I have to check, if the implementation can be simplified to option 3. In the message classes there's a lot of db-related implementation, I have to check, if this is really specific for every message type or can be simplified in a base class,

Answer (score 2):

You can implement Adaptor pattern and keep datasource( any DB or other data source) as an external entity to reduce the coupling.